# Select query for Multiple tables with one Common Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

a select query for Multiple tables with one Common Column

i have tried something below but not working

```
Select *  from DM_Audit da,  DM_APPLICANTS dap , DM_POLICY dp, DM_Names dn,DM_Address ad 
where da.fk_applicationID=dap.fk_applicationID and
dap.fk_applicationID=dp.fk_applicationID and 
dp.fk_applicationID=dn.fk_applicationID and
dn.fk_applicationID=ad.fk_applicationID
```

Here fk_applicationID is Common column in all the table

New to the Sql Please Help

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Trying to retrieve records from multiple tables which have fk_applicationID  as a Common column in all the table

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: And what error do you get? Not working isn't very helpful. What did you expect to see?

Comment: result of above query is not correct because where condition does not covers each  and every tables

Comment: You can use `INNER JOIN`

Comment: ok i ll try never used joins

Comment: Yes you did use joins, you just used old, deprecated syntax. Syntax with JOIN keyword is already 20 years old or so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column name may be the same, but does it reference data for the intended records in each table?

If it definitely does, then re-writing the query using joins would be an easier way of checking the links:

```
Select *  
from DM_Audit da  
INNER JOIN DM_APPLICANTS dap ON dap.fk_applicationID=da.fk_applicationID
etc........
```

I would usually have a 'key' table in this situation (i.e. with the most data in it, or one which links to the most other tables which need to be joined) Then it is much easier to join the other tables.

N.B. if not all tables join to the key table, join as many as you can first, then join to the 'joined' tables further down the statement.